# Getting a RGBA byte array from a BufferedImage Java

Tags: java, image, png, bufferedimage

I have a BufferedImage and would like to get a byte array in the format R G B A (one channel per byte). How can I do this?

Comment: Thats just getting the bytes in a png file

Comment: I wonder, is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414259/java-bufferedimage-to-byte-array-and-back

Comment: No, I want to get the RGBA data, nothing else. I need to get the pixels from the raster in this format but the pixel formats are all different for different images I just want a method which can do this in one abstraction

Comment: Is this for LWJGL?  Here's my answer from a few years ago.  Should plug right into your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875161/efficiently-extracting-rgba-buffer-from-bufferedimage/48875283#48875283

Comment: MadProgrammer, from 2014 ->https://stackoverflow.com/a/27538044/2148953

Comment: @markspace that did it mostly, still getting errors on lots of the images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to use `BufferedImage.getRGB` (which despite its name gives you ARGB values), and convert the packed `int[]` to `byte[]` four times as long. Input can be any file `ImageIO` can read, a PNG will work fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));

    int[] argb = image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null, 0, image.getWidth());
    byte[] rgba = intARGBtoByteRGBA(argb);
}

private static byte[] intARGBtoByteRGBA(int[] argb) {
    byte[] rgba = new byte[argb.length * 4];

    for (int i = 0; i < argb.length; i++) {
        rgba[4 * i    ] = (byte) ((argb[i] >> 16) & 0xff); // R
        rgba[4 * i + 1] = (byte) ((argb[i] >>  8) & 0xff); // G
        rgba[4 * i + 2] = (byte) ((argb[i]      ) & 0xff); // B
        rgba[4 * i + 3] = (byte) ((argb[i] >> 24) & 0xff); // A
    }

    return rgba;
}
```

A slightly more fun way, is to create a `BufferedImage` that is backed by a `byte[]` already in RGBA format, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));

    ComponentColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getWidth() * 4, 4, new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3}, null); // R, G, B, A order
    BufferedImage imageToo = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

    // This array will be in the same R, G, B, A order
    byte[] rgbaToo = ((DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer()).getData();

    // Draw the image onto the RGBA buffer, which will be updated immediately
    Graphics2D g = imageToo.createGraphics();
    try {
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
    finally {
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

Which one of the above examples is better to use, depends on the use case.

- If you just need a one time conversion, the first one is probably easier to reason about and works just fine.
- If you need to update the buffer many times over, the second approach might yield better performance.

PS: I get the exact same results using both alternatives for all my test inputs, *except* the ones where the original is in grayscale (using `ColorSpace.CS_GRAY`). I believe this is a known issue that has troubled Java2D users for ages...

Comment: Ive loaded a PNG file, but the color model is different depending on the file and the pixel formats arent always 32 bits per pixel ( r g b a ) so it gives errors. willl this fix it?

Comment: I updated the code examples to use `ImageIO.read(...)` instead of `new BufferedImage`,  to clarify usage. You should be able to use a PNG or any other file format, as long as `ImageIO.read(...)` can read it. The color model of the image does not matter for `BufferedImage.getRGB(...)` (it *aways* returns packed 32 bit ARGB values in sRGB color space).

Comment: Your method worked, but I was still getting some errors on some images, so I decided to try another png library (pngj) which worked, but thank you!

Comment: I don't know what error you are talking about (you have never posted it, nor a sample file causing the problem). It sounds like a problem that is completely unrelated to the `int ARGB` -> `4 byte RGBA` conversion... But I'm happy it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just used the java library PNGJ to load it, and loaded each row accordingly in RGBA format:

```
for(int j = 0; j < reader.imgInfo.rows;j++) {
        IImageLine row = reader.readRow();
        for(int b = 0; b < reader.imgInfo.cols; b++) { 
                int argb = ch == 3 ? ImageLineHelper.getPixelRGB8(row, b) : ch == 4 ? ImageLineHelper.getPixelARGB8(row, b) : 0xFF000000;
```

Which I then shifted into RGBA:

```
pixels.write((argb & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
pixels.write((argb & 0x0000FF00) >> 8 );
pixels.write((argb & 0x000000FF) >> 0 );//neatness lol
pixels.write((argb & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
```

Answer (score -1):

Start with `BufferedImage#getRGB` which returns `ARGB` values no matter the `ColorModel` of the imgage - check its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,int)).

Then use the *default* instance of `ColorModel` to either get the components (`getRed()`, `getGreen()`, ...) or to get an `int` array of the components (e.g. `getComponents()`). Or just split the value returned by `getRGB()`, format is described in `ColorModel#getRGBdefault`.

Eventually the image (or its raster data) can be converted to TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR, so the raster data can be used directly <sub>(just a guess, I never done it)</sub>

Comment: but the bufferedimage isnt in that color model

Comment: I updated the *answer* - the images model does not matter. Important is the model used for the returned value.

Comment: I tried that, it sometimes said 'more than one component per pixel' illegal argument?

Comment: you should show what you tried in the question (and `that` is a bit ambiguous here)